# Pandas shuffle rows within groups in dataframe, leaving the relative groups order intact

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, shuffle

Given the following df:

```
data = {'Org': ['Tom', 'Kelly', 'Rick', 'Dave','Sara','Liz'], 
        'sum': [3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#      Org  sum
# 0    Tom    3
# 1  Kelly    4
# 2   Rick    4
# 3   Dave    4
# 4   Sara    5
# 5    Liz    5
```

I want to shuffle only the duplicate values in that column and keep the sorted order.

Output should look like this:

```
data = {'Org': ['Tom', 'Rick', 'Dave', 'Kelly','Liz','Sara'],
        'sum': [3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#      Org  sum
# 0    Tom    3
# 1   Rick    4
# 2   Dave    4
# 3  Kelly    4
# 4    Liz    5
# 5   Sara    5
```

with `df.sample(frac=1)` it will shuffle all rows, but that is not what I like to achieve.

Comment: Can you clarify if the groups always are contiguous? If not do you want to keep them unchanged? For instance, what should happen if we moved Dave's row to the end in the input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### sorted groups

If your groups are contiguous, and you want to keep the relative order, use [`groupby.sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sample.html):

```
out = df.groupby('sum', sort=False).sample(frac=1)
```

Example output:

```
     Org  sum
0    Tom    3
3   Dave    4
1  Kelly    4
2   Rick    4
5    Liz    5
4   Sara    5
```

If you wand the output sorted by sum, then:

```
out = df.groupby('sum', sort=False).sample(frac=1)
# or
out = df.sample(frac=1).sort_values(by='sum', kind='stable')
```

which will ensure that the groups are sorted, even if they are not sorted in the input.

##### intact groups

Conversely, if you want to leave the original order of the groups fully intact but want to still shuffle within a group, like in this example:

```
     Org  sum
0    Tom    3
1  Kelly    4
2   Rick    4
3   Sara    5
4    Liz    5
5   Dave    4 # this is part of group "4" but we want the row to stay there
```

Then use [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) to shuffle the indices in place, then reindex:

```
out = df.loc[df.groupby('sum', sort=False)['sum']
               .transform(lambda g: g.sample(frac=1).index)]
```

Example output:

```
     Org  sum
0    Tom    3
2   Rick    4
5   Dave    4
4    Liz    5
3   Sara    5
1  Kelly    4 # the group was shuffled, not the absolute position
```